# How to send all files from request by curl library

Tags: php, symfony, curl

I need to send all files from symfony request to another system by curl library.

I create something like a bridge to old plain php system. How can I add files like a post variable?

In fact, I only need to get files to the controller and pass the same `$_FILES` array through curl. (The following code is just a test. I am fully aware of what the security issue should look like. I need help only with the correct sending of files)

```
        $post = '';

        if($request->request->get('complaint')){

            $post = urldecode(http_build_query($request->request->all()));
            $files = array();

            foreach($request->files->all() as $key => $value){
                // How can I add files like a post variable?
                $post .= $myFileInRightFormat;
            }

        }

        $routeName = $request->get('_route');

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->getParameter('medos_url').'/edit/'.$id);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'b2b='.$this->getParameter('medos_token').'&complaint_id='.$id.'&'.$post);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: I don't want to be harsh, but have you tried a search engine with terms like "sending files curl php"?

Comment: I need to use Symfony HttpFoundation component so solutions using plain PHP are not helpful for me

Comment: you're building a curl request, which is plain PHP. `$request->files->all()` is de facto `$_FILES` which is plain PHP. how to handle the $_FILES array, is described at length in the php docs https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php and the search I suggested can work with files in a temporary location as well. I honestly don't understand your comment claiming that solutions using plain PHP wouldn't be helpful ... where do you think symfony should be involved more?

Comment: Symfony overwrites the array and lets it through its factory classes like most native PHP classes through their components. I posted a reply how to solve this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Php Curl send File with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42915125/php-curl-send-file-with-data)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with sending files in the same way as old versions of the library, multidimensional array, multidimensional array containing files, CurlFile and http_build_query().

I believe that by posting the code I will help some people to save some time. I check a lot of solution and code and for me is working only this one:

```
    /**
     * Complaint status list
     * 
     * @Route("/edit/{id}", name="b2b_rma_complain_edit")
     * @Route("/quardian/{id}", name="b2b_rma_complain_quardian_edit")
     * 
     * @return string Twig tpl B2BRMA/Complaint/index.html.twig
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, $id)
    {

        if($request->request->get('complaint')){

            $post = $request->request->all();

            foreach($request->files->all() as $key => $value){
                if($value){
                    $post[$key] =  new \CurlFile($value->getRealPath(), $value->getMimeType(), $value->getClientOriginalName());
                }
            }

        }

        $post['b2b'] = $this->getParameter('medos_token');
        $post['complaint_id'] = $id;

        $routeName = $request->get('_route');

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->getParameter('medos_url').'/edit/'.$id);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->build_post_fields($post));

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        $crawler = new Crawler($response);
        $html = str_replace('btn-success', 'btn-primary', $crawler->filter('#b2b-curl')->html());

        return $this->render('@B2BRMA/Complaint/edit.html.twig', array('id' => $id, 'routeName' => $routeName, 'html' => preg_replace('~>\s+<~', '><', $html)));
    }

    public function build_post_fields($data, $existingKeys='', &$returnArray=[]){

        if(($data instanceof \CURLFile) or !(is_array($data) or is_object($data))){
            $returnArray[$existingKeys]=$data;
            return $returnArray;
        }
        else{
            foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
                $this->build_post_fields($item,$existingKeys?$existingKeys."[$key]":$key,$returnArray);
            }
            return $returnArray;
        }
    }
```

Of course this is only example